# npm start throwing error 'This is related to npm not being able to find a file.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just created a react app, it was working fine but once I restart the editor it is throwing error like this :

```
        Poojas-MacBook-Air:newreact pooja$ npm start
        npm ERR! path /Users/pooja/Desktop/projects/newreact/package.json
        npm ERR! code ENOENT
        npm ERR! errno -2
        npm ERR! syscall open
        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
        '/Users/pooja/Desktop/projects/newreact/package.json'
        npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
        npm ERR! enoent 

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     /Users/pooja/.npm/_logs/2020-11-28T10_27_42_118Z-debug.log
```

Please help if anyone knows about it.

Comment: are you in the file diretry. it is showing package.json is not in the current directry.

Comment: yes in a same directory

Comment: please share your directry file list in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the latest npm (`npm install -g npm`).
2. Add an exception to your antivirus to ignore the node_modules folder in your project.
3. `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
4. `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the PATH is not correct, just open the cmd and `cd` to the address where the **package.json** is and then run `npm start`

Comment: Just had this case! Quicker solution: do `pwd` to see your current path in the console.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because of the running Metro server. If anyone is experiencing this issue in `react-native`, make sure you have stopped the running Metro server instance before entering `npm i <package-name>`.
With `yarn`, I think, there's no such issue.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve package.json file, go to your project folder and find package.json location folder.
Open terminal and make sure your are in correct path where package.json file located.
eg: c://projectfolder/folder1/clientapp> npm start

[image]

Comment: what if I'm trying `npm run ng new`